# How to measure the length of a subpath of an SVG path?

Tags: javascript, svg

Suppose I have an arbitrary SVG path and the user selects two points on that path. How can I calculate the exact length of the subpath between those two points?

I'm somewhat familiar with the [`SVGPathElement` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement), but cannot figure out how to use any of the calls to calculate a path's partial length.

I'm using D3 so a D3 API call would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Two selected points - what data is known about them? x, y coordinates are not enough, since a path can pass many times through the point (x, y).

Comment: It is an open non-overlapping path. But even so, that's irrelevant: the points are guaranteed to be in the path space, not user space. I'm essentially looking for the inverse of `SVGPathElement#getPointAtLength`.

Comment: Unfortunately you must traverse through the path to find the exact length at which your `x` coordinate matches the coordinate of `getPointAtLength`, here is an implementation of something similar http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/3824661

Comment: If you can use Snap.svg, Snap.path.intersection method is useful. http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/cNvB this is sample to get subpath length by cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Duopixel's helpful comment and [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/3824661), here's a small function for calculating the path distance between two *x* coordinates:

```
function pathDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(path, x1, x2) {
    var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
    var distance = 0, distance1;
    while (distance < pathLength && x1 > path.getPointAtLength(distance))
        distance1 = distance++;
    while (distance < pathLength && x2 > path.getPointAtLength(distance))
        distance++;
    return distance - distance1;
}
```

The function runs in *O(n)*, which isn't too bad. A binary search (*O(log n)*) is also possible, but that's overkill for my purposes.

Comment: Would nice to see a simple demo using this. By the way, as long as `distance1` is `null`, it could result in `NaN`. ;)